# Dividing float by double vs dividing double by double in java

Tags: java

When I tried the following codes in Java:

```
System.out.println("0.1d/0.3d is " + 0.1d/0.3d)
System.out.println("0.1f/0.3d is " + 0.1f/0.3d)
```

I get the following output:

```
0.1d/0.3d is 0.33333333333333337
0.1f/0.3d is 0.3333333383003871
```

If float/double should get a double then float/double should be same with double/double in this case.

Comment: No, it's a double, but `0.1d != 0.1f`.

Comment: To get a precise result, just use BigDecimal.

Comment: One actually sees nicely that a float (4 bytes) has about half the precision of double (8 bytes). And 0.1 is in binary an infinite sequence.

Comment: Wait, you're actually demanding same precision for half the cost?

Comment: Double carry 16 precision  `0.1111111111111111d/0.3d`  no matter how much you added to the precision above 16 digit it will be the same, and float carry 8 precision `0.11111111f/0.3d` no matter how much you added to the precision place above 8 digit it will be the same value, Therefore you can't get the same value, as double use 64bits and float use 32bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute the below code to see binary string of number you want to check for:

```
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToLongBits(0.1d)));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(0.1f)));
```

**Output:**

> 11111110111001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
>
> 111101110011001100110011001101

And you see the difference in float bits and double bits. so we can't get the same result for float/double and double/double for a longer precision values .

Answer (score 1):

yes "milbrandt" said right when we are converting float quantity into double by implicit typecasting some information at decimal point will differ. That's why it is showing the different result while dividing **float/ double.**

Comment: What additional value does this answer provide?

Comment: As above value mentioned the same result will print after execution. The difference appeared because of typecasting.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, `double` uses 64 bits to store a value but `float` 32 bits.

To represent significand, `double` uses 52 bits, and `float` uses 23 bits. Thus `double` can give 15 digit precision at most, and `float` can give 7.

If you do `float / double`, you actually try to divide a floating point with 7 digit precision at most (far to exact) by a floating point with 15 digit precision at most (closer to exact), and then implicitly typecast the result to a floating point with 15 digit precision. The typecast cannot restore your result from 7 digit precision to 15 digit. Therefore, the results are different though both of them are `double`.

Answer (score 0):

initialize a double with a float and divide then. You will see the same result.

```
    double f = 0.1f;
    double d = 0.1d;
    double n = 0.3d;

    System.out.println("float /double = " + f/n);
    System.out.println("double/double = " + d/n);
```

result is

```
float /double = 0.3333333383003871
double/double = 0.33333333333333337
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking "why does this happen?".

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see this difference is because you don't have these exact values.

Even if we suppose `0.1d` and `0.3d` would be exact (which they aren't, what you can see on the result `0.33333333333333337`), `0.1f` is `0.10000000149011612`, which makes the difference.